# What is this last part when i display my generated SQL from query in c#? And can i remove it?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

When i generate my Query from C# it shows this

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[RegionName] AS [RegionName] 
FROM [dbo].[RegionClasses] AS [Extent1] 
WHERE ([Extent1].[RegionName] = @p__linq__0) 
  OR (([Extent1].[RegionName] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
```

But the problem is where last "OR" is. Why is it there and how do i remove it? what does it do?

below is my code for the query from C#:

```
var RegionlinqQuery = from regions
                      in ctx.Regions
                      where regions.RegionName == SearchTextBox.Text
                      select regions;

string sqlQuery = RegionlinqQuery.ToString();
RegionLabel.Text = sqlQuery;
```

Comment: Its comparing null RegionName with null SearchTextBox.Text and considering them equal

Comment: In sql, if a field is null, you cannot compare it with `=` that is why the generated query has that `is null` part.

Comment: @MatJ is there a way to remove it, by editing the code in query? or is it just impossible if i have to compare the texbox with the name?

Comment: Note by the way that the compiler will optimize this down to just `WHERE ([Extent1].[RegionName] IS @p__linq__0)` which isn't valid as SQL text, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6728e329b9ba3ff86dda96db030876c0

Comment: @Charlieface i see i see, thank you, the thing was i needed just for myself to understand more clearly how it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the `context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics` to disable this behavior. You can check the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: Well, OP also asked *"what does it do?"* so this may not be what they need. Without understanding the semantics, it's probably just an *I-don't-understand-this-so-take-it-away!* kind of freak-out reaction. They apply this solution and then their code doesn't work when they want to compare with null, and wonder why *that* doesn't work now.